# Executing a fetch request on another thread

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I want to make a CoreData fetch request on a background thread in order to give the user the option to cancel it.

Below is my background thread code:

```
- (void)searchDailyNotes
{
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
            entityForName:@"DailyNotes"
            inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    NSString *searchString = [self.searchTextField stringValue];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest= [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate
            predicateWithFormat:@"notes contains[cd] %@", searchString];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error = nil;
    [_dailyNotesArray addObjectsFromArray:
            [self.managedObjectContext
             executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest
             error:&error]];

    NSLog(@"dailynotesArray count: %lu", [_dailyNotesArray count]);
    if(error){
        [NSApp presentError:error];
    }
    [fetchRequest release];
}
```

Questions:

- If the user wants to cancel the search, what would be the corrrect way to terminate the background thread?
- If I abort the thread while the `managedObjectContext` is currently fetching, what would happen to the allocation of `fetchRequest`? Would I have a leak?

Comment: you might be interested in this series of articles: http://www.cimgf.com/2011/05/04/core-data-and-threads-without-the-headache/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocoa threading doesn't generally include the idea of forcing a thread to abort. You'll see a `cancel` method, but that's strictly advisory. The idea is that the code in the thread will check this state periodically and exit early if a cancel has been requested. You'll see this in `NSThread` and `NSOperation`, for example. If the code doesn't check for a cancel request, the `cancel` method has no effect.

Because of that, you'll need to add checks for a cancel request if you want to handle cancellation. If you see that a cancel was requested, you can do whatever cleanup you need before actually finishing the thread. But you can't interrupt the fetch request in progress anyway-- once you've called the method to start it, you wait until it finishes.

On a separate note, how long do your fetches take that you actually need to worry about this situation?